# ClassNotFoundException and BIND_EXTERNAL_SERVICE and crash with Android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

An extremely simple app, API level 24 (Android 7.0), trying to load a WebView in the only activity, on an actual physical device, gives the following in the log and stops the app:

```
I/cr_DRP: No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp
```

and

```
W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: BIND_EXTERNAL_SERVICE failed, ComponentInfo{com.android.webview/org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0} is not an externalService
```

and

```
A/chromium: [FATAL:jni_android.cc(233)] Check failed: false. Please include Java exception stack in crash report
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 6989 (Chrome_ProcessL)
```

What is going on? Some kind of version/dependency problems? How can it be corrected?

XML for WebView:

```
<WebView
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

WebView code:

```
mWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");
```

Full project: https://github.com/qabi/webviewtest

Comment: maybe this is helping: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45592011/1019850 or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736890/no-drp-key-due-to-exceptionjava-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-android-webvie

Comment: @David, unfortunately I already read these items, and I don't think they are relavant in this case. It seems to be Chromium somehow missing. I don't think external storage write permission should be required (and all tutorials on WebView doesn't say anything about this). The other issue seems to be a bad/differing browser implementation in an emulator. In my case I cannot start the WebView at all. Actually I think the ClassNotFoundException might be misleading, and not have anything to do with the actual problem (the BIND_EXTERNAL_SERVICE fail and subsequent crash).

Comment: Can you show your actual webview creation code, and ideally the page it is loading?

Comment: What URL are you trying to load with WebView?

Comment: Added details. Nothing fancy - simple plain WebView declared, and google.com loaded. That's all.

Comment: Is this problem in opening a special web page or for every webpage you are trying to open it happens?

Comment: there might be a permission request problem. You checked?

Comment: I happens for every website. For example google.com. I checked the INTERNET permission, which should be the only one required. The example is really, extremely simple. Maybe a problem with the device ROM?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing similar issue with `java.lang.SecurityException: BIND_EXTERNAL_SERVICE`, in my case internet permission was missing in manifest.xml.

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
```

Comment: Have tried with and without this permission, but same symptoms (crash) regardless.

Answer (score 0):

having not yet enabled JavaScript appears to be a possible reason (it's disabled by default):

```
mWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");
```

Comment: Tried this, but no improvement.

Comment: @DennisThrysøe could you add the whole stack-trace and the `AndroidManifest.xml`? think the issue is probably rather caused by wrongful settings in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, than the `WebView`. as the question is currently written, this barely is something reproducible - and that's why people try to guess. also dependency issues are impossible to reproduce without the `build.gradle`. or share it on GitHub, to have the issue reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

First check the permission is given correctly in manifest.

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
```

If this is included when we loading the url by default it try to redirect to chrome browser. I think this is causing the crash. Not sure anyway. Add following code to stop it.

```
 mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){                   
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return false; // then it is not handled by default action
           }
});
```

Comment: Tried both of these things, but no improvement.

Comment: I have run your github code in pixel 2 its working. Also run with API 24 emulator and loading the web page correctly. This seem like s problem with your testing device.

Comment: Thanks. I tried emulator also. I feared this might be the problem. Will investigate this further.

Answer (score 0):

Webview object will be wv

```
   wv.setWebChromeClient(
            new WebChromeClient() {

                long mStartRX = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
                long mStartTX = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();


                @Override
                public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID) {
                    Log.d("MyApplication", message + " -- From line "
                            + lineNumber + " of "
                            + sourceID);
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                    super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);

                    long rxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() - mStartRX;
                    long txBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - mStartTX;

                    Log.d("TRAFFIC", "Current Bytes Rx ==>   " + rxBytes
                            + "   Bytes Tx ==>   " + txBytes
                            + " New progress ==> "  + newProgress);
                }
    });
   wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            wv.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }



        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);


        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my testing device. Everywhere except this one WebView works.

This testing device is a POS terminal without Chrome or any other browser. I think the problem is related to this.

The solution that worked on my device:

Go to settings -> Developer options -> Disable Multiprocess WebView

After this WebView works.